# How to create an if statement that has a list in its condition?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I put my question in the notes of the code.
I am new to programming. I will more and likely not understand very technical responses. Please, if you can, explain it in the easiest way.

```
while i < len(stored):
    # I'd like this to break if any of these values are zero. How do I do that?
    if (x, y, z, t) == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Do not host your code off-site, and do not upload a picture of your code. Include the code as text in the question.

Comment: You may also use `not all((x, y, z, t))` as an alternative to the mentioned answers

Comment: This was my first question. I am so sorry. I will type code in the future.@WillDaSilva

Comment: so I could put if 0 not all (list): ?@MoinuddinQuadri

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri why not put that information as an answer to the question?

Comment: @MichaelRamageMikeRamage No, just `if not all((x, y, z, t))`.

Comment: @waterproof Because this question is already been closed as duplicate and my answer doesn't fits to the linked question

Answer (score 1):

```
while i <= len(stored):
    if 0 in (x, y, z, t):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
while i <= len(stored):
    if 0 in (x, y, z, t):
        break;
```

Comment: That makes sense. I appreciate the help on that. I have one more question. Do you mind helping?

Comment: This also be improved by using a `set()` for faster membership testing.

Comment: @ChristianDean not necessarily since sets are expensive to construct. If you could construct the set once and use it multiple times in the loop though, you're probably right.

Comment: @waterproof Well yes. In that respect you are right. But like you mentioned, I meant creating a set _outside_ of the loop, and using that. I should have been more specific.

Comment: yep. it's not clear where (x, y, z, t) are coming from but that could be possible.

Comment: x,y,z, and t are to be stored with append. Order matters because I later user their indexes to create a while loop.